# Get RawContactId of specific Contact based off PhoneLookup

Tags: android, android-contacts

I am looking to get the `RAW_CONTACT_ID` of a specific `Contact` using `PhoneLookup` or even just the Contacts LookupKey.

I know the contacts table has a column `name_raw_contact_id` that references the `raw_contacts._id` column but it doesn't seem to be returned when querying `ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_LOOKUP_URI` with the contacts lookup key.

My phone lookup query is:

```
String[] projection = new String[] { 
    PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME, PhoneLookup.LOOKUP_KEY };
Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri.encode(number));
Cursor c = resolver.query(uri, projection, null, null, null);
```

Then I am looking up the `Contact` based on the lookup key:

```
String[] contactProjection = new String[] { 
    ContactsContract.Contacts.NAME_RAW_CONTACT_ID 
};
Uri contactUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(
    ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_LOOKUP_URI, lookupKey);
Cursor contactCursor = resolver.query(contactUri, 
    contactProjection, null, null, null);
```

However, this doesn't compile and I get

```
cannot find symbol: variable NAME_RAW_CONTACT_ID 
location: class android.provider.ContactsContract.Contacts
```

But the [android documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.Contacts.html) shows `NAME_RAW_CONTACT_ID` as a column.

Is there any way I can get the `RAW_CONTACT_ID` based off either phone number or lookup key?

Comment: In other examples that I've seen, `number` has to be encoded. E.g.
`Uri lookupUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri.encode(phoneNumber));`. Why is it not in your example?

Comment: At the time (pre ICS), it wasn't needed and googles docs didn't have it in their example(that I recall). I never ran into any issues doing it this way; perhaps they have updated it in ICS to want an encoded phone. Google's docs on this have `Uri.encode(phoneNumber)` now as well so I'll update my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found that the answer is to make a third query:

```
long rawContactId = -1;
Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(RawContacts.CONTENT_URI,
    new String[]{RawContacts._ID},
    RawContacts.CONTACT_ID + "=?",
    new String[]{String.valueOf(contactId)}, null);
try {
    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        rawContactId = c.getLong(0);
    }
} finally {
    c.close();
}
```

But it should be noted that there can be multiple RawContact's per one Contact and the above query will get ALL RawContact's associated with the `contactId`

Answer (score 1):

ContactsContract.Contacts.NAME_RAW_CONTACT_ID column needs **API level 21** or greater so make sure your are compiling with this version.
Also you can use **ContactsContract.PhoneLookup._ID** column in your first query to get the ***Contact_Id*** and then use this **Contact_Id** in your 3rd query so your problem will be solved in 2 queries instead of 3.

Answer (score 0):

```
private HashSet<Long> getRawContactIdsForContact(long contactId)
{
    HashSet<Long> ids = new HashSet<Long>();

    Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(RawContacts.CONTENT_URI,
              new String[]{RawContacts._ID},
              RawContacts.CONTACT_ID + "=?",
              new String[]{String.valueOf(contactId)}, null);

    if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst())
    {
        do
        {
            ids.add(cursor.getLong(0));
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        cursor.close();
    }

    return ids;
}
```